# How do I dynamically add to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is a Windows C program. In the below code I'm converting a delimited char (pbliblist) into an array. The array is passed to a function from a third party.

My question is how can this be done without knowing how many entries there are (libcount). I was thinking I might be able to 'new' each array entry within the token loop.

```
LPCTSTR * LibList = new LPCTSTR[libcount];
token = strtok_s(pbliblist, seps, &next_token);
while (token != NULL) {
    LibList[cnt] = token;
    token = strtok_s(NULL, seps, &next_token);
    cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Your question says C, but your code uses `new`, which is not a thing in C.  Please choose a language: either C or C++.

Comment: and if its C++, you don't dynamically add an array, you use one of the existing containers instead

Comment: Short answer: If your C string is null terminated you can tell its size (`strlen`).
If not, then calling `strtok` has an undefined behavior.

Comment: What is `LPCTSTR`? Create a [mcve]

Comment: @eerorika it's a Win32 thing. Stands for "Long Pointer to a constant TCHAR string" basically `const tchar*` where it could compile to a `char` or `wchar` depending on project definitions.

Comment: @Andy - there is no `wchar` type in C++ nor in the windows API.   `TCHAR` either expands to `char` or `wchar_t`.     In some versions of the windows API, that occurs by (depending on project settings) by `TCHAR` expanding to `WCHAR` (note the case) which expands to `wchar_t`.

Comment: sorry, forgot the `_t`

Comment: @Andy Ah, I see. Do the project definitions also affect the argument of `strtok_s`?

Comment: @eerorika -- nope. because `strtok_s` is ONLY for `char` arrays. He should be using `_tcstok_s`

Comment: This isn't compiled as Unicode. It is a C program with .cpp file extension so I can use some C++ features like new and std::string.

Answer (score 0):

There's different ways you can do it.

But, right off the bat, out of the box, you can't just "add" to an array in C, and, honestly, you don't want to.

There's a couple things you can try.

One, is to assume the size. If you know, for example, that there won't be more than 100 fields in the string, then you can just use 100 for libcount. This "wastes" memory, but it's really efficient, because it's allocated only once. Just make sure you check for the boundary condition and signal an error if you go over 100, because "it should never happen".

Now, if you do the 100 thing, at the end, now that you do, indeed, know how many items you read, you can then create a NEW array, exactly as big as you want, copy the elements from the original array, free it, and return the new one.

Similarly, continuing down this path, there's no need to `new` the original 100 array. Simply allocate it on the stack, parse the elements in to it, and at the end copy them to the newly allocated result array. The ones on the stack "vanish" when the stack unwinds (super cheap).

If you don't want to have any limit, you can still expand on the above concept.

Start with an original array (but this time, you'll want to allocate it). Then start filling it up. When it fills, and you have more coming, create a new, bigger array, copy the old one to the new one, and release the old one.

In the end, you'll have everything in a single array. You don't want to do this for each element, however. You don't want to new 4 bytes, then new 8 bytes, then new 12 bytes, copying all the time. If you do that you fragment your heap something awful, and you copy way, way to much.

Instead you do it in chunks. 10 entries, 20 entries, 40 entries.

At the end, you can, like above, copy the array a last time to a correctly size block of memory (or not, if this array is going to be returned and destroyed 5ms later, kind of "who cares" about the excess at the end).

Finally, of course, since you're talking C++, there's something in the template libraries that does all this for you (not that I know what it is, I imagine you could just push to extend a vector). But, see, I can barely spell C++, so...don't defer to me for expertise and details on that.

Comment: Thanks! The code is in .cpp files so I can use C++ features like new and std::string. I'm not using any C++ classes and have no idea what templates or vectors are.

Comment: Well, the standard classes and templates are worth looking in to. They're pretty fundamental to modern C++. And using them solves this problem readily.